# A partial order is a preorder that has no clique

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

In *Category Theory for the Sciences*, by David I. Spivak, p. 169 just after Definition 4.4.1.14 ([available online](http://category-theory.mitpress.mit.edu/chapter004.html#lev_4-4)), the author asserts that:

> A partial order is a preorder that has no nontrivial clique.

To, me, this reads as: $\textrm{partial order} \Rightarrow \textrm{has no non trivial cliques}$

I have no problem with this, but, in exercice 4.4.3.3, he uses the fact that a particular preorder has no non trivial clique to prove that it is a partial order.

This seems wrong to me, as a preorder can have no non trivial clique, yet still have cycles (by which I mean an $R$-path that starts and ends at the same element and has more than two different elements). And if it has cycles it is not a partial order. I have not proved it, but intuitively I would have imagined that $\textrm{partial order} \Leftrightarrow \textrm{has no cycles}$

**EDIT:** As an example of a preorder that has no non trivial cliques but is not a partial order, let $S = \{a, b, c, d\}$ and

\begin{equation}
R \subset S \times S = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c,), (d,d), (a,b), (b,c), (c,d), (d,a)}
\end{equation}

It has no non trivial cliques, but it is not a partial order, because for example, $a \leq c$ and $c \leq a$, but $a \neq c$.

Since the author appears to use the fact that $\textrm{has no non trivial cliques} \Rightarrow \textrm{partial order}$, I really feel I misunderstood something, so any clarification would help.

Comment: In definitions the word "if" must always be red as "if and only if". So you should read it as $\text{partial order}\iff\text{preorder having no non trivial cliques}$

Comment: I think this equivalence is wrong, and added a counter example in my main post.

Comment: Then $\{a,c\}$ is a nontrivial clique.

Comment: OK, that clarifies it :).

Comment: I am not even familiar with the word "clique". What I do know is that a preorder is reflexive and transitive. If $P$ denotes a preorder then it induces an equivalence $E$ by stating that $xEy\iff xPy\wedge yPx$. The equivalence classes can be singletons (so trivial in a sense). Preorder $P$ will be a partial order if and only if all equivalence classes (I suspect they correspond with cliques, whatever that is) are singletons. In that case $P$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: @drhab The term is defined in the link vkubicki provided, though it would not have hurt for the OP to have inlined the definition. Specifically, a clique of a preorder $S$ is a subset $S'$ such that $\forall a,b\in S'.a\leq b$. More generally, [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) is a common graph theory term and corresponds to a complete subgraph. Both of these coincide when viewing the $\leq$ relation as a directed graph on $S$, and maximal cliques will correspond to the equivalence classes you mention.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you for info and link. I am a bit wiser again.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I forgot some elements in the relation, hence the misunderstanding you helped clear.